# How to save a ToggleControl value in a meta field?

Tags: custom-field, javascript, post-meta, block-editor

I registered a boolean meta field called `_meta_restrict` in a custom post type:

**PHP:**

```
function register_meta_fields() {
    register_post_meta( 'custom_post_type', '_meta_restrict', array(
        'show_in_rest' => true,
        'single' => true,
        'type' => 'boolean',
        'auth_callback' => function() {
            return current_user_can( 'edit_posts' );
        }
    ) );
}
add_action( 'init', 'register_meta_fields' );
```

**JS:**

```
let RestrictControl = ({ restrict, onUpdateRestrict }) => (
    <ToggleControl
        label={ 'Restrict access?' }
        help={ restrict ? 'Access is restricted.' : 'Access is not restricted.' }
        checked={ restrict }
        onChange={ restrict => onUpdateRestrict( restrict ) }
    />
);

RestrictControl = compose( [
    withSelect( ( select ) => {
        return {
            restrict: select( 'core/editor' ).getEditedPostAttribute( 'meta' )['_meta_restrict']
        };
    } ),
    withDispatch( ( dispatch ) => {
        return {
            onUpdateRestrict: ( value ) => {
                dispatch( 'core/editor' ).editPost({ meta: { _meta_restrict: value } })
            }
        }
    } ),
] )( RestrictControl );
```

I added this meta field using a `ToggleControl` to the `PluginDocumentSettingPanel` and I can toggle it on and off, but when I save changes, the `_meta_restrict` key is stored in the database with an empty value.

What am I doing wrong?

Thanks in advance